# Barracuda 240 LoadBalancer doesn't seem to balance. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: load-balancing, barracuda

I have a Barracuda 240 load balancer which is supposed to balance traffic between 2 servers.

The public ip address is showing to balance between two internal ones (192.168.10.2/3), but looking at the logs I only traffic on the 2nd server on the list, not the first.

The setup is to use Weighted Least Connections. Both servers have the same weight of 100.

A short while ago we had to recreate our LB configuration and since it seems this started. 
At the moment traffic is low, but I do recall seeing the servers being balanced before that LB config was recreated.

Is what I'm seeing to do only with low traffic, or is there something I can check regarding the setup?

Many Thanks
Harel

Comment: Thanks guys, this helps a lot. 
It seems like everything is ok a day or two later, when traffic picked up, although both your comments help me understand the LB better. 
H

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, Barracuda uses LVS. It's well documented.  Do you have Barracuda support?

There's a lot of checkboxes in Barracuda that could potentially affect the specific performance.

Try multiple clients accessing simultaneously from different locations.  I typically refresh a Web browser while I'm running `ipvsadm -L -n` and it doesn't take too long for several connections to show up on an otherwise idle LVS VIP.

[Linux Virtual Server](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/)
[Weighted Least Connections](http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Weighted_Least-Connection_Scheduling)

Answer (score 0):

If you shut down your second server, can you still get to your website? If not, it's definitely not load balancing.

Do you see any connections in the Health tab of the load balancer?

Under Services, are both of your servers enabled? Which test are you using to check status and how often do you check?

Why not change to round robin from least connections just to see if that fixes things?

Which Barracuda firmware are you running? If it's older than a year or two, you probably want to pay up for the support and get an upgrade.